# How can I get the current gps location every time a function is called?

Tags: java, android, geolocation

What I want to do is to get the location latitude and longitude each time a function is called. As I have understood the best way to do that is to leave the location update for a few seconds to get the correct fix and then disable it, but I can't make it work in my app.

What I have managed until now is to get the last known location of the phone, every time the displayData function is called, but I have not been able to get over all the errors that appear when I'm trying to change to requestLocationUpdates. What exactly I am doing here is to call the displayData function, when there is incoming data from a bluetooth device, in order to get the location and write the data + location in a file.

Can someone help me because all the guides show how to trigger something when location updates but I don't want to do that. **I just want a correct location periodically...**

```
private void displayData(final byte[] byteArray) {
try {

    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.

                    if (byteArray != null) {
                        String data = new String(byteArray);
                        tv.setText(n/2 + " measurements since startup...");
                        n += 1;

                        if (location != null) {
                            double lat = location.getLatitude();
                            double lng = location.getLongitude();
                            latitude = String.valueOf(lat);
                            longitude = String.valueOf(lng);
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(textfile,true); //the true will append the new data
                            if (writeDate()) {
                                fw.write("\n");
                                fw.write(stringDate);
                                fw.write(data); //appends the string to the file
                            }
                            else {
                                fw.write(data); //appends the string to the file
                                fw.write(" - ");
                                fw.write(latitude);
                                fw.write(",");
                                fw.write(longitude);
                            }
                            fw.close();
                        }
                        catch(IOException ioe)
                        {
                            System.err.println("IOException: " + ioe.getMessage());
                        }


                        // find the amount we need to scroll. This works by
                        // asking the TextView's internal layout for the position
                        // of the final line and then subtracting the TextView's height
                        final int scrollAmount = tv.getLayout().getLineTop(
                                tv.getLineCount())
                                - tv.getHeight();
                        // if there is no need to scroll, scrollAmount will be <=0
                        if (scrollAmount > 0)
                            tv.scrollTo(0, scrollAmount);
                        else
                            tv.scrollTo(0, 0);
                    }
                }
            });

} catch (SecurityException e) {
    // lets the user know there is a problem with the gps
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could decouple getting/maintaining the location and calling `displayData()`. Just have a variable for the latest location and use it in `displayData()`. Then worry about maintaining the up-to-date location separately based on how accurate is absolutely needs to be and how fast is the device supposed to move. If the speed is high and the location needs to be accurate, you probably could just request location updates and keep them coming. Otherwise you can maybe just update periodically by requesting the updates, receiving a one or a few and then canceling them to save the battery.

Comment: This could be justified, because getting the location is asynchronous and your `displayData()` apparently should be synchronous and not wait for some other operation to finish. But you know your app better.

Comment: Thank you Markus. I like your approach also. If I want to save battery I could set a value of minTime (to update the location) equivalent to the period of the displayData repetition and I will be fine, not? If I'm getting the updated location "outside" displayData I could even leave this code as it is and use the last known location which will be pretty accurate, right?

Comment: Yes, the "last known location" will be as good (the same) as the latest location returned by the `onLocationChanged()` callback. Theoretically it could be different if some other application is requesting location updates too. Possibly even with "worse" settings. Storing the value received in  `onLocationChanged()` would be a safer way then, perhaps. I haven't actually tested that scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed Markus Kauppinen's approach requesting for location updates at a time interval that suits my app and then just using the get last known location when there is incoming data from bluetooth. So I just added the following in my activity:

```
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(30000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    LocationCallback mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback();



// Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
    try {
        mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
                mLocationCallback,
                null /* Looper */);

    }
    catch (SecurityException e) {
        // lets the user know there is a problem with the gps
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I understand of your problem:

- You want GPS location on demand, but:
- You don't want the GPS to run constantly, and:
- You accept that the GPS will have to be run for a short period of time

Try not to think in terms of a "function that returns the phone's current location", because that implies that it's a simple, synchronous operation that provides an answer without blocking. We can't do that here.

Instead, I suggest you think of this more as an [FSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), since you need an arbitrary amount of time (perhaps a few seconds, perhaps more) between the time you call `displayData()` and the time you start getting real-time GPS fixes. In other words, `displayData()` will not produce a location, directly; it'll set into motion a chain of events which eventually results in you obtaining a location.

You'll have to commit to using `requestLocationUpdates()` (or a similar method):

```
private void displayData(final byte[] byteArray) {
    //This call turns the GPS on, and returns immediately:
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {

        //This function gets called some time after displayData() returns (possibly
        //*way* after). It executes on the UI thread.
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(this); //Shut down the GPS

            //(Execute the remainder of your onSuccess() logic here.)

            //Now our state machine is complete, and everything is cleaned up.
            //We are ready for the next call to displayData().
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    );
}
```

That way,

- We don't block the UI thread (`displayData()` returns immediately)
- The state machine eventually converges to an answer (provided the GPS is functional)
- GPS turns off once we have the information we need

Some improvements to this scheme you might want to consider:

- A way to avoid a repeat call to `requestLocationUpdates()` if `displayData()` gets called before the previous request has resolved
- Handling the case where the UI elements referred to in your `onSuccess()` method are no longer available b/c the Activity has `onDestroy()'d` during the time the GPS request was "in progress"
- Cancelling the request-in-progress if you need to clean up, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it and tell you, but at your example I think we have the onLocationChanged executed only one time (and that will be many meters away from the actual location, not?). Or am I missing something  and the onLocationChanged returns after doing a good job even once? If not, I would like to have the onLocationChanged run a few times (seconds) to make a better fix before writing the location, so I guess I could try something like Markus suggests in his comment?

Comment: I haven't tested this code. But since GPS_PROVIDER is specified, I don't think it's gonna give you a stale fix. The first time `onLocationChanged()` fires, it should be high accuracy. But your suggestion (like counting to 2 before you call `removeUpdates()`), or @markus-kauppinen's, are perfectly valid ways of doing things too.